# null exception because of calling a class

Tags: selenium

Tried implementing calling a java class from a different package to improve the efficiency of my test scripts.
Before I rewrite login.java on every class now tried calling it to be more efficient , now what happens is , it logins properly but does not follow up.

Tried separating login.java

```
package BaseClass;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login extends OpenBrowser {


    //Open Brower           
    @Test
    public void LoginWebSystem() {              

        driver.get("http://localhost:82");  
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("login_username"));
        email.sendKeys("superadmin");   
        System.out.println("Username Set"); 
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("login_password"));
        password.sendKeys("nelsoft121586"); 
        System.out.println("Password Set"); 
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit"));
        login.click();
        System.out.println("Login Button Clicked"); 
    }       
    //If login is successful or failed
    @Test (priority=1)
    public void LoginAccount() {
    String newUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    if(newUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost:82/controlpanel.php")){
        System.out.println("Login Success ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Login Failed");
    }
    }
    //Proceed to product page
}
```

Test2.java

```
  package BaseClass;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;


public class test2 extends BaseClass.Login {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test (priority=2)
    public void ProductPage() {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Product")));         
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Product")).click();
        System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Product Page");

    }

}
```

Should work properly without no error

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is wrong with my code? I want to call a class so that my script is efficient . Want to make the extend work

Comment: What do you mean by "it logins properly but does not follow up"?

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException? And if so, what line is throwing this exception?

Comment: at BaseClass.test2.ProductPage(test2.java:19)

Comment: Looks like you never initialized `driver`. Anyway, you should add the full stack strace to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)